# Error creating contexts in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to create a ProductContext from a list of dummyProducts in React-Typescript. The following is the code that I am using:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { dummyProducts } from '../constants/dummyProducts';
export const ProductsContext = createContext();

const ProductsContextProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {

    const [products] = useState(dummyProducts);
    return ( 
        <ProductsContext.Provider value={{products}} >
            { children }
        </ProductsContext.Provider>
     );
}
export default ProductsContextProvider;
```

BUt I am getting following error:

```
(alias) createContext<unknown>(defaultValue: unknown): React.Context<unknown>
import createContext
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(381, 9): An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.
```

I have also tried to use like this:

```
 - createContext({});
 - createContext(null);
 - interface IProducts {
        name: string,
        id: string
    }
    createContext<IProducts>();

    //But getting this error: 
    interface IProducts
    Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
    index.d.ts(381, 9): An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.
```

I am not sure how can I add products interface to support our dummy products for creating a context. What else could I try?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela that is not correct

Answer (score 0):

[React.createContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) requires an argument for `defaultValue`. You can pass `undefined` if you do not want any specific default value:

```js
export const ProductsContext = createContext(undefined);
```

Comment: While I use this, I am getting the following error:

Type '{ products: { id: number; name: string; price: number; photo: string; details: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(333, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<undefined>'

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `createContext` a type and a default value. Since according to the docs:

> The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree.

As long as you are using a `Provider`, you can just pass it an empty object like:

```
export const ProductsContext = createContext<IProducts>({} as IProducts);
```

or if you are using an array of `IProducts` you can just pass it an empty array:

```
export const ProductsContext = createContext<IProducts[]>([]);
```